# what will moving variable to the code segment do in assembly?

Tags: variables, assembly, segment

when I do

```
 mov [cs:10], dl
```

what change does it make in the code?
isn't dl stored in the data segment?

thank you

Comment: Depends on what sort of environment the program is running under.

Comment: + Depends on the opcode on this address and wich value is in DL loaded before. If CS=DS, then the segment override prefix is not needed and otherwise there is no reference to the data segment in this instruction. Writing into the codesegment is usable in the real address mode for to manipulate the instruction while the executable is running. For example, we can load the opcode for the "inc" instruction into the DL register for to replace a "dec" instruction in the codesegment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what change does it make in the code?

The instruction `mov [cs:10], dl` does not necessarily change anything to **the code**. It just overwrites whatever byte value that is at address 10 in the code segment. This byte could contain (part of) an instruction or it could contain just data.

> isn't dl stored in the data segment?

Since the instruction had a CS: segment override the DL register contents are stored in the code segment. Without this segment override the DL register contents would have been stored in the data segment addressed by DS.

> what will moving **variable** to the code segment do in assembly?

The assembly language needs you to be exact. The instruction does not reference any variable. It envolves a register.

Comment: and what will happend when the ip get to the 10 line in the code segment?

Comment: Not all combinations of values are valid instructions, but the cpu can only execute valid instructions and we have to carry that the instruction pointer only target to valid instructions.

Comment: why do you want to do such a thing?